# how to round-trip an xarray.Dataset through it's own groupby method

Tags: python-xarray

The `xarray.Dataset.groupby` method prepares a dataset for iteration over subsets determined by the `group` argument. If the `group` argument is a constant value (i.e. one "subset" that's the whole dataset) broadcast to an `xarray.DataArray` with matching coordinates, then I expect the first group returned to be identical to the original dataset. And that's what happens when the dataset coordinates are dimension coordinates. It **doesn't** happen for this dataset

```
ds_before = xr.Dataset(coords={'x': ('z', [0]), 'y': ('y', [1, 2])})
```

which prints as

```
Dimensions:  (z: 1, y: 2)
Coordinates:
    x        (z) int64 0
  * y        (y) int64 1 2
Dimensions without coordinates: z
Data variables:
    *empty*
```

Coordinate `x` is a non-dimension coordinate. If you switched `z` to `x` above, then `ds_after` produced by the following would be identical to `ds_before`.

```
da = xr.DataArray(True, coords=ds_before.coords)
key, value = next(iter(ds.groupby(da)))
ds_after = value.unstack()
```

The printed representation of `ds_after` is not identical to `ds_before`.

```
Dimensions:  (z: 1, y: 2)
Coordinates:
  * z        (z) int64 0
  * y        (y) int64 1 2
    x        (z, y) int64 0 0
Data variables:
    *empty*
```

I can work around the new dimension coordinate `z`, but I don't understand why `x` has been broadcast along the `y` dimension. Can you suggest a method for getting `x` back to its original value?

Comment: You’re grouping a dataset in two dimensions (y and z). Any variables will therefore be broadcast against the two dimensions. If you only grouped on y this wouldn’t be the case.  So this is expected and there’s no way to set up a multidimensional groupby where this doesn’t happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @MichaelDelgado on the question appears correct in part, but there is a way to combine `groupby` with `sel` to achieve the desired result.

```py
>>> ds_before = xr.Dataset(
        data_vars={'a': ('y', [0.1, 2.3])},
        coords={'x': ('z', [0]), 'y': ('y', [1, 2])}
        )
>>> da = xr.DataArray(True, coords=ds_before.coords)
>>> idx = next((group.unstack().indexes for label, group in da.groupby(da)))
>>> ds_after = ds_before.sel(idx)
>>> print(ds_after)
Dimensions:  (y: 2, z: 1)
Coordinates:
    x        (z) int64 0
  * y        (y) int64 1 2
Dimensions without coordinates: z
Data variables:
    a        (y) float64 0.1 2.3
```

This is not round tripping a dataset through *its own* group by method, but it does preserve the original dimensions on `a` and `x`. Using this method with a `da` that is not constant (so there are multiple groups) also preserves the original dimensions.